# How to send headers using swr

Tags: reactjs, swr

I am trying to send headers using [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/data-fetching) and Axios but the headers are not being sent.

```
 const fetcher = (url) =>
    axios
      .get(url, { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token } })
      .then((res) => res.data);
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/get-avatar`,
    fetcher
  );
  if (error) console.log(error);
  if (data) console.log(data);
```

What is the correct way to send headers with SWR?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As per the docs https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments you should do

```
const fetcher = (url, token) =>
    axios
      .get(url, { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token } })
      .then((res) => res.data);

const { data, error } = useSWR(
  [`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/get-avatar`, auth.token],
  fetcher
);
if (error) console.log(error);
if (data) console.log(data);
```

Comment: How does the SWR know to pass the header key as "Authorization"? and, how do I pass the custom headers?

Comment: SWR only consider [url, token] combination, you can decide the headers as you want. @RaviTejaVupasi

Comment: @RaviTejaVupasi, it doesn't. Keep in mind that an remote fetching comes from fetcher functions that are supplied by you, so you just configure it there.  SWR hands the rest -- caching, mutation subscriptions, etc.  The URL that is passed to the useSWR() hook just serves as a key that marks all data accessed that way as 'dirty' and worthy of revalidation (refetching).  It is not telling SWR to fetch.  That's up to the fetcher function.

Comment: In this version of the hook, the URL / key is passed to the fetcher, but that is just for convenience.  One can just as well have the URL hard-coded in the fetcher and supply a key that is some other string.  The purpose of the key is so that all other components that use it get updated when the data is mutated.

Comment: why the document does not describe like you?! They say useSWR(['/api/user', token], ([url, token]) => fetchWithToken(url, token)). Using this, in the fetcher function body, token is undefined

Comment: The code is not the same as in the docs (just similar, hence does not work). `const { data: user } = useSWR(['/api/user', token], ([url, token]) => fetchWithToken(url, token))` https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#multiple-arguments