# ExpressJS returning empty object when logging req.cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, cookies

I have an express server set up like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.cookies)
  res.send();
});

app.listen(5000);
```

And the output of this is an empty object, but in my client-side (that is making the request), if I log `document.cookie` it prints a string with many values. Any idea why the same is not showing up in the server log?

EDIT`: the exact log is `[Object: null prototype] {}`

This is the request:

```
const login = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:5000", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({msg: "example"}),
  });
  
};

login();
```

Comment: can you show me the cookie?

Comment: Do you mean what is logged when I type ```document.cookie```  into the browser console?`

Comment: yes, is the format of cookie like this:  `somethin=something`

Comment: Ok here you go id=2; csrftoken=plLDHj4jaAaH3Uow5Cj3cpBtupcIBIy8892834GfE9PLY8CF7oofwAWGveKK"

Comment: do you send the request with axios or fech?

Comment: Can you show me the request?

Comment: Check the question, I added it

Comment: do you append cookie to the header in the request?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you. But I was using the useSWR hooks in ReactJS and found the solution thanks to that post : [How to send headers using swr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862928/how-to-send-headers-using-swr).

Try your code with the `"credentials" : include` in your request like this:

```
const login = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:5000", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    "credentials" : include,
    body: JSON.stringify({msg: "example"}),
  });
  
};

login();
```